# Error : 'Unable to evaluate named property or non-integer index 'id' on an array value.'

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I am new to bicep and trying to deploy a keyvault with access policies. In my scenario, environments like dev and load can have common access policies, but prod should have region specific access policies.

Below is the code for access policy code within the kv module -

**kv-vault.bicep**

```
param objectIds object

resource KeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' = {
  name: KeyVaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    tenantId: 'abcdxyz'
    accessPolicies: [for objectId in items(objectIds): {
        objectId: objectId.value.id
        tenantId: 'abcdxyz'
        permissions: {
          keys:objectId.value.key
          secrets: objectId.value.secret
          certificates:objectId.value.certificate
        }
      }]
   }
}
```

Below is how I am calling the kv module in my main.bicep file

**main.bicep**

```
var objectid = isAME ? (isLOAD || isDEV || isQA ? common.objectIds 
               : common.objectIds.us) 
               : isEMA ? (isLOAD || isDEV || isQA ? common.objectIds 
               : common.objectIds.ema) 
               :  (isLOAD || isDEV || isQA ? common.objectIds 
               : common.objectIds.apa) 

module KeyVault './modules/key-vault.bicep' = {
  name: 'keyvaultdeployment-${uniqueName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
  params: {
    objectIds: objectid
    KeyVaultName: KeyVaultName
    location: rg.outputs.location
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
    rg
  ]
}
```

And I have a common file where all the object id's are being passed.

**commom.json**

```
  "objectIds":{
    "us": {
      "id": "abcd-1234",
      "key": ["all"],
      "secret": ["all"],
      "certificate": ["all"]
    },
    "apa": {
      "id": "abcd-4567",
      "key": ["all"],
      "secret": ["all"],
      "certificate": ["all"]
    },
    "ema": {
      "id": "abcd-7890",
      "key": ["all"],
      "secret": ["all"],
      "certificate": ["all"]
    }
}
```

So, when I am trying to deploy in prod in EMA, it should only pickup the 'ema' from the common.jason file. But I am getting an error -
'Unable to evaluate named property or non-integer index 'id' on an array value.'

Please help me out. Let me know if you need any further information on the existing code. Thanks in Advance.

I tried all the basic troubleshooting and going through Microsoft doc, but didn't help me out.

Comment: You are only passing in a single object, why use `items()` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call into the `key-vault.bicep` module in EMA, the value passed in for will either be:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "apa",
        "value": {
            "id": "abcd-4567",
            "key": [
                "all"
            ],
            "secret": [
                "all"
            ],
            "certificate": [
                "all"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ema",
        "value": {
            "id": "abcd-7890",
            "key": [
                "all"
            ],
            "secret": [
                "all"
            ],
            "certificate": [
                "all"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "us",
        "value": {
            "id": "abcd-1234",
            "key": [
                "all"
            ],
            "secret": [
                "all"
            ],
            "certificate": [
                "all"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

or

```json
[
    {
        "key": "certificate",
        "value": [
            "all"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "id",
        "value": "abcd-7890"
    },
    {
        "key": "key",
        "value": [
            "all"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "secret",
        "value": [
            "all"
        ]
    }
]
```

If it's the latter, the `key-vault.bicep` template will try to dereference the `.id` property of `["all"]` on the first iteration of the loop. Arrays won't have an ID property, leading to their error message you saw.